# Should new posts already have tags?

Tags: posts, tags

When creating a new post on one of my multi sites post tags have automatically been added. This happens to some users on specific sites only. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: You need to rule out that this is not a plugin or theme fault.

Comment: too true - Ive determined its actually from manual editing / copying tables in the db. Relationships shouldnt exist for object ids that dont exist in the posts table. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer - no they should not. Potential errors caused by plugins, theme or manually manipulating tables in wp db.